# Fulltext Search for string with quotes

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to perform a fulltext search for a string that contains quotes, so for example the string being `["test1","test2","test1test"]` and i want to search only for `"test1"`, so it should not return `"test1test"`.

I plan to use this in a procedure where the string to search is an (unqouted) input parameter, so the quotes need to be added around that parameter before matching it).
The call for the example above would be `CALL sarch("test");`

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: This is a little bit confusing. So the example string wouldn't match if you searched for "test1"?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `=`, it will will do full word match as you are expecting.

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TEXTCOL = 'text1';
```

This will return only rows with exact value i.e. `text1`.

On the other hand,  If you want to perform contains kind of search(which you are trying to avoid), you may use `LIKE` operator as:

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TEXTCOL LIKE '%text1%';//text1 anywhere in the string
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TEXTCOL LIKE '%text1'; //text1 with any prefix 
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TEXTCOL LIKE 'text1%'; //text1 with any suffix
```

If not, then please provide explicit details about your requirement.